# how to change json structure in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a json Object like following.

```
{987: "sqa", 988: "Squad"}
```

I need to change the structure like following

```
[{id:987, value:'sqa'}, {id:988, value:'Squad'}]
```

How to do this with Javascript?

Comment: What you want is not really a valid json format. There are multiple `id`s and `value`s

Comment: The second is no valid JSON.

Comment: You are talking about JS objects, not JSON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2):

You could get the entries of the object and map new objects in an array.

Techniques:

- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for getting all key/value pairs from an object in an array,
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), for mapping a new item for each item of the array,
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the key/value pair and
- [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for taking the name as key and the value as value for an object.

```js
var object = { 987: "sqa", 988: "Squad" },
    result = Object.entries(object).map(([id, value]) => ({ id, value }));
   
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written invalid JSON in your question, but I assume you want it as a JavaScript object.

Something like this perhaps.

```js
var oldObj = {
    987: "sqa",
    988: "Squad"
}

var newArray = [];

for (let k in oldObj) {
    newArray.push({'id': k, 'value': oldObj[k]});
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const intial = {987: "sqa", 988: "Squad"}  
const final = [];
for(let idNum in intial){
  const data = {
    id: idNum,
    value: intial[idNum]
   }
  final.push(data);
}
console.log(final);  //[ { id: '987', value: 'sqa' }, { id: '988', value: 'Squad' } ]
```

This will achieve what you're trying to do